# iCloud calendar: Getting unauthorized error from CalDav server

Tags: calendar, icloud, caldav, icloud-api

I'm trying to PUT an event on iCloud calendar using CalDav. After several proper requests and responses and getting the user principal and calendars, when i try to PUT an event, the server returns Unauthorized error.

Here's the network log from fiddler:

Request:

```
OPTIONS https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
Host: p49-caldav.icloud.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: AppleHttpServer/1.9.12/0643601
Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2016 15:38:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Apple-Jingle-Correlation-Key: X27XPFLXYFCYHGGADAAWWCKMJE
apple-seq: 0
apple-tk: false
X-Responding-Instance: caldavj:44900101:pv42p49ic-zteg05101201:8501:16D67:82b3920
Allow: ACL, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
DAV: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-managed-attachments, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-subscribed, calendarserver-home-sync
X-Accept-Client-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: icloudedge:br30p01ic-ztde01120601:7401:16D44:Berlin
X-Apple-Request-UUID: bebf7795-77c1-4583-98c0-18016b094c49
X-Apple-Xrail: false
access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
access-control-expose-headers: Via
```

Request:

```
PROPFIND https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
Depth: 0
Host: p49-caldav.icloud.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 89

<propfind xmlns="DAV:">
  <prop>
    <current-user-principal />
  </prop>
</propfind>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: AppleHttpServer/1.9.12/0643601
Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2016 15:38:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 350
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "B40001-1B000-578A54FB"
Last-Modified: Sat, 16 Jul 2016 15:38:35 GMT
DAV: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-managed-attachments, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-subscribed, calendarserver-home-sync
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Responding-Server: pv42p49ic-zteg04102301 21 a63660a6f7d1a25b5a7ed66dab0da843
X-Transaction-Id: b8d02729-1bcd-4df1-a1ce-3c2a545ed3f0
Vary: accept-encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: icloudedge:br30p01ic-ztde01120601:7401:16D44:Berlin
X-Apple-Request-UUID: b8d02729-1bcd-4df1-a1ce-3c2a545ed3f0
X-Apple-Xrail: false
access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
access-control-expose-headers: Via

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multistatus xmlns='DAV:'>
  <response>
    <href>/</href>
    <propstat>
      <prop>
        <current-user-principal>
          <href>/10430699202/principal/</href>
        </current-user-principal>
      </prop>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
  </response>
</multistatus>
```

Request:

```
PROPFIND https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/10430699202/principal/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
Depth: 0
Host: p49-caldav.icloud.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 122

<propfind xmlns="DAV:">
  <prop>
    <calendar-home-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" />
  </prop>
</propfind>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: AppleHttpServer/1.9.12/0643601
Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2016 15:38:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 446
Connection: keep-alive
DAV: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-managed-attachments, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-subscribed, calendarserver-home-sync
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Responding-Server: pv42p49ic-zteg04102001 22 a63660a6f7d1a25b5a7ed66dab0da843
X-Transaction-Id: 9b4aa58d-69d9-4e82-bd90-48380b1650cc
Vary: accept-encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: icloudedge:br30p01ic-ztde01120601:7401:16D44:Berlin
X-Apple-Request-UUID: 9b4aa58d-69d9-4e82-bd90-48380b1650cc
X-Apple-Xrail: false
access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
access-control-expose-headers: Via

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multistatus xmlns='DAV:'>
  <response>
    <href>/10430699202/principal/</href>
    <propstat>
      <prop>
        <calendar-home-set xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
          <href xmlns='DAV:'>https://p49-caldav.icloud.com:443/10430699202/calendars/</href>
        </calendar-home-set>
      </prop>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
  </response>
</multistatus>
```

Request:

```
PUT https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/10430699202/calendars/ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd.ics HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
Host: p49-caldav.icloud.com
If-None-Match: *
Content-Type: text/calendar
Content-Length: 302

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//tracky/iCal//FUBU v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20160716T202635
DTSTAMP:20160716T155652Z
DTSTART:20160716T202635
LAST-MODIFIED:20160716T155652Z
SEQUENCE:1468684613
SUMMARY:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AppleHttpServer/1.9.12/0643601
Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2016 15:56:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 216
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/10430699202/calendars/ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd.ics/
X-Responding-Server: pv42p49ic-zteg04092901 6 a63660a6f7d1a25b5a7ed66dab0da843
X-Transaction-Id: e537a470-ddf6-4a8f-a059-580d52075840
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: icloudedge:br30p01ic-ztde01130201:7401:16D44:Berlin
X-Apple-Request-UUID: e537a470-ddf6-4a8f-a059-580d52075840
X-Apple-Xrail: false
access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
access-control-expose-headers: Via

<html><head><title>Moved Permanently</title></head><body><h1>Moved Permanently</h1><p>Document moved to https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/10430699202/calendars/ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd.ics/.</p></body></html>
```

The server redirects me and removes the authorization header causing the unauthorized error:

```
PUT https://p49-caldav.icloud.com/10430699202/calendars/ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd.ics/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
If-None-Match: *
Content-Type: text/calendar
Host: p49-caldav.icloud.com
Content-Length: 302

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//tracky/iCal//FUBU v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20160716T202635
DTSTAMP:20160716T155652Z
DTSTART:20160716T202635
LAST-MODIFIED:20160716T155652Z
SEQUENCE:1468684613
SUMMARY:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: AppleHttpServer/1.9.12/0643601
Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2016 15:56:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 141
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: x-mobileme-authtoken realm="MMCalDav"
WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="MMCalDav"
X-Responding-Server: pv42p49ic-zteg05101701 1 a63660a6f7d1a25b5a7ed66dab0da843
X-Transaction-Id: 25cf8cf5-3c86-4c11-915f-f51ee9c79c86
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: icloudedge:br30p01ic-ztde01130201:7401:16D44:Berlin
X-Apple-Request-UUID: 25cf8cf5-3c86-4c11-915f-f51ee9c79c86
X-Apple-Xrail: false
access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
access-control-expose-headers: Via

<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body><h1>Unauthorized</h1><p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p></body></html>
```

When I targeted the redirecting URL encountered another error:

```
<html><head><title>Conflict</title></head><body><h1>Conflict</h1><p>cannot PUT to non-existent parent</p></body></html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `PUT` an event into the calendar homeset collection:

```
PUT https://p49-caldav.icloud.com
  /10430699202       # user scope
  /calendars         # calendar home
  /???               # calendar
  /ee451a47-c242-40c1-b295-4f1251a5d0cd.ics # event
```

A calendar homeset contains calendars, not events. So the next step is selecting the calendar you want to put your event into (e.g. the [default calendar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638#section-4.3)).

You can list the available calendars (and todo lists) with another `PROPFIND Depth:1` on the homeset.

Comment: Could you please clarify this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799968/icloud-calendar-empty-response