# iCloud Calendar empty response

Tags: icloud, caldav

I have sent below request to iCloud calendar service to get all calendar list. But response is always empty. Can anyone help me?

**Request:**

```
GET /10232836851/calendars/F41F7478-4345-4A4A-8CD5-548122EF2C22/ HTTP/1.1
HOST: pxx-caldav.icloud.com
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==
depth: 1
content-type: text/xml
```

**Response Header:**

```
Server: AppleHttpServer/a6f3179
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 07:35:53 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 19:32:45 GMT
Dav: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-managed-attachments, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-subscribed, calendarserver-home-sync
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Responding-Server: pv41p47ic-tydg09053001 23 a63660a6f7d1a25b5a7ed66dab0da843:44702101
X-Transaction-Id: 55b238a2-548b-41fc-acc0-b697adb4ab84
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Via: icloudedge:hk02p00ic-ztde010805:7401:16G8:Hong Kong
X-Apple-Request-Uuid: 55b238a2-548b-41fc-acc0-b697adb4ab84
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID; Via
```

Comment: Finally i got response by changing request method PROFIND. How to filter calendar with date specific by sending parameter

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of calendars on the server using the `CalDAV` protocol you use the `PROPFIND` method, not a `GET`. This is pretty well described in the [SabreDAV Building a CalDAV Client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/#retrieving-calendar-information) web page.

Something like this:

```
PROPFIND /calendars/johndoe/ HTTP/1.1
Depth: 1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: ...
Authorization: ...

<propfind xmlns="DAV:">
  <prop>
     <displayname />
  </prop>
</propfind>
```