# iCloud Calendar Requests

Tags: curl, icloud, caldav, icloud-api

I'm trying to access the my iCloud calendars through `curl` (using this as a test before I write any code), but am getting *unauthorised access* errors. Has anyone had any luck in getting this to work? I've used [this](http://ict4g.net/adolfo/notes/2015/07/04/determing-url-of-caldav.html) to extract my *user ID* and have determined by server ID by emailing myself an event invite.

Command run

```
curl -u <apple email ID> https://<server id>-caldav.icloud.com/<user id>/calendars
```

Response

```
<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body><h1>Unauthorized</h1><p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p></body></html>
```

*Edit*

I've tried to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413296/icloud-calendar-getting-unauthorized-error-from-caldav-server?rq=1) query using fiddler but keep getting a 502 response - connection failed with `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 10):

To access iCloud calendars or reminders you use an IETF protocol called
[CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV).
[Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)
is a great introduction on how to do this.
With the above you are just throwing a `GET` request at the API ...

Using curl it is a 3-step process to get to, say, the calendar names. First
you need to figure out the URL representing your iCloud account (called a
*Principal* in WebDAV speak):

```
curl -s -X PROPFIND -u "$APPLEID" -H "Depth: 0" \
  --data "<propfind xmlns='DAV:'><prop><current-user-principal/></prop></propfind>" \
  https://caldav.icloud.com/
```

If you can't get to authenticate against that, you are using wrong credentials, you may have enabled two-step verification for your iCloud account, or it is past 2017-06-15: "App specific passwords will be required to sign in to iCloud with third party apps from June 15".
In this case you need to setup an
[app-specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397)
for CalDAV access.

The curl above shows you the URL of your account record, it looks
something like `https://caldav.icloud.com/347723822/principal/`.
The next step is figuring out where your calendars are hosted. That is stored
in the account's `calendar-home-set` property of the principal and can be
accessed like so:

```
curl -s -X PROPFIND -u "$APPLEID" -H "Depth: 0" \
  --data "<propfind xmlns='DAV:' xmlns:cd='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'><prop><cd:calendar-home-set/></prop></propfind>" \
  https://caldav.icloud.com/827267162/principal/
```

This gives you the reference to the cluster the actual calendars lives on,
it looks something like
`https://p22-caldav.icloud.com:443/827161622/calendars`.
Lets say you want to get the names of all the calendars the user has:

```
curl -s -X PROPFIND -u "$APPLEID" -H "Depth: 1" \
  --data "<propfind xmlns='DAV:'><prop><displayname/></prop></propfind>" \
  https://p42-caldav.icloud.com:443/28377271/calendars/ \
| grep displayname
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for posting this extensive answer. I have the exact same problem as OP and tried your first curl command with -v (verbose) and got 401. I am 100% certain my credentials are correct. Same are used when I login to icloud.com and work. No 2-FA active. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: I suppose it is this: https://www.google.de/amp/s/9to5mac.com/2017/05/16/app-specific-passwords-will-be-required-to-sign-in-to-icloud-with-third-party-apps-from-june-15-heres-how-to-make-them/amp/

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: @hnh In my case, when I execute the your last step I get `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`. Do you have any idea what's the possible scenario that causes this?

Comment: Wrong credentials or URL.